# Prolog existence_error procedure in basic example

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I'm trying to learn the basics of Prolog and keep running into a existence_error with the following code.

```
comes_after(m1, m2).
comes_after(m2, m3).
comes_after(m3, m4).
comes_after(m4, m5).
comes_after(m5, m6).

does_come_after(X, Y) :- comes_after(X, Y).
does_come_after(X, Z) :- comes_after(X, Y), does_come_after(Y, Z).
```

When executing a query such as does_come_after(m1, m3) I keep getting the following error.

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,comes_after/0),does_come_after/0)
```

Here's a screenshot showing the error:

[Prolog Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOOqm.png)

What am I doing wrong, and what should I keep in mind to avoid these errors in the future? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks alright, although your logic of does_come_after is probably a bit flawed. shouldn't cause this error however. How exactly did  you call the logic?

Comment: Seems that you haven't consult the file which contains the predicates...

Comment: I did consult the file, and I tested it using the comes_after() predicate. I updated the post, check the screenshot for specifics. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message tells you that Prolog expects a predicate `comes_after/0`, but none is found. Further, this problem arises when being called from a predicate `does_come_after/0`. Now, your definitions all use arity 2. Thus `comes_after/2` and `does_come_after/2`. So what the system expects cannot happen.

And if it does, this must be related to your installation.  You have 1.4.5 which is the most recent version, 1.4.4 the still current stable.

It is thus possible that you have another, older, system installed which interferes by providing an incompatible `pl2wam` compiler. To verify this, say `which pl2wam` or `pl2wam --version`.

In particular, versions from 1.3 or even 1.2 may produce such results. There is no version checking for this in GNU.

To ensure that I get always the right version, I say:

```
 export PATH=/opt/gupu/gprolog-1.4.5/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right about the version thing. Looks like others have had the same problem as well: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/users-prolog/2017-02/threads.html

I downgraded to 1.4.4 and that seems to have resolved the issues!

Comment: @Zoro : Updated

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, this is a problem with version 1.4.5.

Instead of downgrading, fortunately, there is a trick that you can do:

Instead of using consult(file_name) inside gprolog, you can run this command on your terminal (outside gprolog)

```
    gplc file_name.pl
```

it will output an executable that you can run by

```
    ./file_name
```

it should solve your existence error problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GNU prolog, and following Illham's advice, you should create a file (i.e `my-fancy-definitions.pl`) and then load it by either:

1. By command line: `$ gprolog --consult-file my-fancy-definitions`, or
2. From the running interpreter: `[my-fancy-definitions].`